# How to run Derby as a background process in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, derby

I am using derby on a remote Ubuntu 12.04 server.  The standard derby commands are all working correctly and I am able to open my databases and access them via ij.  I need to be able to start and stop the server from the terminal while logging in and out between commands.  The problem is that I can not find a way to run the server as a background process.  The closest I have come is: `nohup java -jar $DERBY_HOME/lib/derbyrun.jar server start & > ~/dblog.txt` which works except that it requires I hit [enter] before returning to the command line.  I am aware of the daemon package but I am uncertain of whether it will allow me to then stop the server.  What would be helpful is a explanation of how tomcat manages it since that is my app server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use commands like "kill" or "killall" to kill your background process. Use "jobs" command to see list of running process you've sent to background. Also you can put them back in foreground by doing - "fg %n" (where n is the job number) and kill it using CTRL-C.

Comment: I didn't ask my question clearly enough.  I want to know how to make the Derby process run in the background.  This is a problem that seems to be Derby specific rather than Java or Linux.  I have seen the question asked repeatedly with no answers.

Comment: Hmm. Understand. But, if you can send a process in background with '&' from command line, then you should get it back with 'fg' command. But, since you're saying that things with Derby is different (and I don't have knowledge of derby), so can't tell. What I've posted that's generic - suppose to work with any Linux process.

Comment: It is good to know how to that.  Now if I could just get the command line to not require an additional [Enter].

Comment: To accomplish every command need to pass an enter :). Even if when we start services like. 'service httpd start' we need to press enter. I think it's not a big issue.

Comment: Thank you.  I din't realize that this was a normal Linux behavior.

Comment: I have gone back to this question to select an answer.  When I wrote this question I didn't understand the nohup portion.  Simply passing a n & ended up being the solution. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

Derby is just a Java application. Any technique you wish to use to run Java applications in the background (/etc/init.d, job control in your shell, etc.) will work fine for Derby.

Comment: This is true but it is not behaving like a regular java app.  I could run it though /etc/init.d  but I want to have greater control over it because I am frequently starting it and stopping to preserve state.

Comment: I didn't understand the use of nohup when I wrote this.